# TCP client not auto-connect to server

Tags: c++, tcpclient, epoll

I am creating a TCP Client with the ability to reconnect when the server is inactive.

I have a TcpClient class:

```
class TcpClient {
public:
   TcpClient(std::string host, int port);
   void Start();
   void Recive();
   bool IsConnected() const { return _connected; }
   int sock() const { return _sock; }
private:
   std::string _host;
   int _port, _sock;
   bool _connected;
   struct sockaddr_storage _addr;
};



void TcpClient::Start() {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    
    char port_str[16];
    snprintf(port_str, sizeof(port_str), "%d", _port);
    
    struct addrinfo *result;
    if (getaddrinfo(_host.c_str(), port_str, &hints, &result) != 0)
        Error << "getaddrinfo: " << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
    
    int family = result[0].ai_family;
    int protocol = result[0].ai_protocol;
    socklen_t addr_len = result[0].ai_addrlen;
    //struct sockaddr_storage addr;
    memcpy(&_addr, result[0].ai_addr, addr_len);
    
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    
    _sock = socket(family, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, protocol);
    if (_sock == -1)
        Error << "socket: " << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
    
    if (connect(_sock, (const struct sockaddr*) &_addr, sizeof(_addr)) == -1) {
        _connected = false;
        Error << "Connected to " << _host << ":" << _port 
              << " not installed. (" << std::strerror(errno) << ")\n";
    }
    else {
        _connected = true;
        Info << "Connection to " << _host << ":" << _port << " found.\n";
    }
}


void TcpClient::Recive() {
    uint8_t data[256];
    if (IsConnected() == true) {
        int res = recv(_sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), 256, 0);
        
        if (res == -1 || res == 0) {
            
            Error << "Connection to " << _host << ":" << _port 
                  << " to cut off. (" << std::strerror(errno) << ")\n";
            _connected = false;
        }
        else {
            // handler data...
        }
    }
    else {
        if (connect(_sock, (const struct sockaddr*) &_addr, sizeof(_addr)) == -1) {
            _connected = false;
            Error << "Connection to " << _host << ":" << _port 
                  << " no installed. (" << std::strerror(errno) << ")\n";
        }
        else {
            _connected = true;
            Info << "Connection to " << _host << ":" << _port << " installed.\n";
    }
    }
}
```

I register `_sock` and `TcpClient::Recive()`  in `epoll`, then in `while(1)` I wait for events to occur:

```
int main() {
   TcpClient client("127.0.0.1", 1234);
   client.Start();
   Reactor reactor;
   std::function<void()> cb = std::bind(&TcpClient::Recive, &client);
   reactor.RegisterHandler(client.sock(), cb, TypeEvent::kRead);
   while(1)
      rector.Wait(); 
}
```

The behavior of the program is as follows:

```
1. Server is off, client is on:

    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" not installed. (Operation now in progress)
    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" not installed. (Connection refused)
    .....

2. I turn on the server.

    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" installed.

3. I turn off the server.

    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" to cut off. (Operation now in progress)
    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" not installed. (Transport endpoint is already connected)
    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" not installed. (Transport endpoint is already connected)
    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" not installed. (Transport endpoint is already connected)
    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" not installed. (Transport endpoint is already connected)
    .....

4. I turn on the server.

    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" not installed. (Transport endpoint is already connected)
    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" not installed. (Transport endpoint is already connected)
    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" not installed. (Transport endpoint is already connected)
    Connection to "127.0.0.1:1234" not installed. (Transport endpoint is already connected)
    ....
```

The connection was not restored.

I read on the Internet that you need to close the `close(_sock)` socket and configure it again.
To do this, me may have to create a TimerEvent that will reconnect to the server.

Please help me to solve the problem of reconnecting to the server.

Comment: After a socket is disconnected you need to close it and make a new one.

Comment: It is a good idea.